# Catch quadruple click in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am developing an React app in which i have to implement t9 typing in which we have to simulate the typing of keypad phones

```
(ie . say if i click the button containing 'p q r s'
on:
long press : shows 7
single click: shows p
double click shows q
triple click shows r
quadruple click : should show 's' but my code shows 'rp'
```

What i have done i have set an onclick listener to td of html table (which i am using to render as key of key pad phone)  and find no. Of times it has been clicked by event.detail . in some case i need to capture a quadruple click (eg. if i have to type 's') but when i click an element more than 3 it resets event.detail to 1 and start again.[image: here hows the ui looks like]

Code of onclick listener:

```
<tbody>
          {array.map((i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                {values.slice(3 * i, 3 * i + 3).map((val) => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      key={val.str1}
                      onClick={fxn}
                      className={val.str2}
                      id={val.str1}
                      onMouseDown={startTimer}
                      onMouseUp={clear}
                      onMouseLeave={clear}
                    >
                      <h2>{val.str1}</h2>
                      {val.str1 !== val.str2 && <h5>{val.str2}</h5>}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
```

Code of fxn:

```
const fxn = (event) => {
    var string = event.currentTarget.className;
    var s2 = event.currentTarget.id;
    var times = event.detail;
    if (count === display.length) {
      if (s2 === string || s2 === "0") {
        setDisplay(display + string);
      } else {
        if (times < 2) {
          setDisplay(display + string[(times - 1) * 2]);
        } else {
          setDisplay(display.slice(0, -1) + string[(times - 1) * 2]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is the full code in case you need to see:
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leaf-4k62s 
Is there any method to capture the quadruple click?

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: This is unfortunately not a free code-writing service site: please refer to [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Moreover you have shared a video that is private, and whatever information that is needed for the question to be answered should be contained within the question here instead of on an external resource.

Comment: @Kinglish Can you help know?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that when there are more than 3-4 clicks, `string[(times-1)*2]` returned `undefined`.

What I did:

- Got rid of the `timeout` and all related functions because we know that it was a multiple click by analyzing `event.detail` number.
- Added `<pre>` in the display so consecutive white spaces would not be squashed.
- Specified `key` as `val.str1` in `<td>` as it was always giving `[object Object]` console error.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const values = [
  { str1: "1", str2: ". , !" }, { str1: "2", str2: "a b c" }, { str1: "3", str2: "d e f" },
  { str1: "4", str2: "g h i" }, { str1: "5", str2: "j k l" }, { str1: "6", str2: "m n o" },
  { str1: "7", str2: "p q r s" }, { str1: "8", str2: "t u v" }, { str1: "9", str2: "w x y z" },
  { str1: "*", str2: "*" }, { str1: "0", str2: " " }, { str1: "#", str2: "#" }
];
const rows = [0, 1, 2, 3];

let clickStart = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("");

  const fxn = (event) => {
    const duration = new Date() - clickStart;
    console.log(duration);
    const string = event.currentTarget.className;
    const name = event.currentTarget.id;

    if (isNaN(name) || name === "0") {
      setDisplay(display + string);
      return;
    }

    const values = string.split(" ");
    const times = event.detail;
    const char = values[(times - 1)% values.length];
    setDisplay((times === 1 ? display : display.slice(0, -1)) + char);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Glamplus Internship Puzzle</h1>
      <h2>--made by Prince Yadav</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan={3}>
              <pre>{display}</pre>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                {values.slice(3 * i, 3 * i + 3).map((val) => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      key={val.str1}
                      onMouseDown={() => (clickStart = new Date())}
                      onMouseUp={fxn}
                      className={val.str2}
                      id={val.str1}
                    >
                      <h2>{val.str1}</h2>
                      {val.str1 !== val.str2 && <h5>{val.str2}</h5>}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i made changes suggested by you but it still not working for the pqrs case.it skips the second letter says 'b' in 'a b c' if we use times in calculation const char. and when we use (times-1) in place of times it works same as previous ie. display 'rp' on quadurple click (ie the same behaviour before trying changes suggested by you)

Comment: And the timer is used to simulate a long press. so no need to remove it

Comment: @PrinceYadav I fixed the bug you mentioned and added the duration variable to the handler. Since I don't know what should be displayed on a long click, just logging it.

Comment: I have applied your changes . Still the problem is same. ie. it is showing 'rp' instead of 's' in case of quadruple click. I have edited my question . you can check it to fully understand what i am saying. Link of updated code is : https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leaf-4k62s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @PrinceYadav It works for me if I'm using computer, 4 clicks on number 7 give "s". But I discovered that if I open it in mobile view using devtools, it prints out "pppp" and thinks that every click is a new one. For now I don't know if that can be fixed.